# Can i load username and password by file in spring boot + hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, spring-boot

I want to use spring boot, oracle db and hibernate. I want to load username and password for oracle db schema by two files( user.txt and password.txt). Can i use hibernate? I don't know how to load the username and the password from file in application.properties for hibernate. (spring.datasource.username = load from user.txt,
spring.datasource.password = load from password.txt). User and password are encrypted in files.

Does anyone have an idea how i do that?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: There are way better approaches to hide your passwords https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37404703/spring-boot-how-to-hide-passwords-in-properties-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do it but using property files, not txt files. If you are willing to follow this approach your options are:

1. @PorpertySources in your configuration class. An example is

   ```
   @PropertySources({
           @PropertySource("/user.properties"),
           @PropertySource("/password.properties")
   }). 
   @Configuration
   public configClass{
       @Value("{db.user}")
       private String user;
       @Value("{db.password}")
       private String password;
       ...
   }
   ```

db.user and db.password must be defined in your config files. With these data you can define your data source (you will need the connection url as well )

2. If you are using hibernate configuration file you can find an example in this answer:
   [How to read database configuration parameter using properties file in hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25684785/how-to-read-database-configuration-parameter-using-properties-file-in-hibernate)

Comment: Thanks, but user and password are encrypted in files, and i need two different files for user and password.

Comment: In that case I guess you will need to create your coustom proper source. You have to create a class extending PropertySource<Object> and implement the method  public Object getProperty(String name). In this class you will be able to access the encrypted files, decrypt them and parse them to retrieve de properties you need. You will need as well to register the property source in the env doing env.getPropertySources().addFirst(new YourCustomPropertySource(param)); example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416005/spring-environment-property-source-configuration

Comment: Thanks, i will try this!

Comment: Hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Just add another application.properties outside of the .jar, which includes the database information.  See spring docs -> https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

Place your application.properties outside of your packaged jar file. Spring Boot will look in the same directory for properties and the values can be accessed as if the file was inside the classpath.